# How can I display and list all PDF files in a directory in an HTML Table, in their descending order of their upload date?

Tags: php, pdf

I have made an upload.php which makes it possible for the user to upload file on server in their respective folders, based on the drop-down selections. It also renames the file with the date, the user sets.
Now, I want to display all those PDF's in a specific directory within a table. I have found this code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?php
    $files = scandir('./uploads/ffbl/daily');
    rsort($files); // this does the sorting
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
      echo'<tr><td><a href="/uploads/ffbl/daily/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td></tr>';
    }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it displays all the files, not only PDF's. Moreover, files should be in descending order of their upload date / time.

Answer (score 2):

If the sorting is working, you could check each file extension within the foreach:

see [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for more info

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
  $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if($ext == 'pdf' || $ext == 'word'){
      echo'<tr><td><a href="/uploads/ffbl/daily/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td></tr>';
  }
}
```

For more extensive sorting you could place each file into an array and sort the array. This would also allow you to perform the file extension check at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering, I got it done :)
Initially, I was saving the files as **'10 Nov 2016 - BLAA - BLAA Report'**. I changed it to something like **'20161011 - BLAA - BLAA Report'**, while saving it on server. And used formatting to convert it to the format I wanted it to appear in website later on. Saving date in numeric form helped me perform comparison on list of files in directory easily. Instead of scandir, I used **glob**. Instead of using alphabetical sort, I used **natsort** (Natural Sort - because I had to make the application consider multi-digit numbers as single characters) inside a function which also **reverses the array** (for displaying in descending order). Sample code is attached for reference:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
    $files = glob('./uploads/ffbl/daily/*.pdf');

    function returnFile($file)
    {
      $date = substr(basename($file), 06, 2);
      $month = substr(basename($file), 04, 2);
      $year = substr(basename($file), 00, 04);

      $finalDate = date("d M Y", strtotime("$year-$month-$date"));

      return $finalDate;
    }

    function natrsort(&$files)
    {
      natsort($files);
      $files = array_reverse($files);
    }
    natrsort($files);

  ?>

// later in the table body


<?php
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
          echo'<tr><td><a href="ViewerJS/#.'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.returnFile($file).'</a></td></tr>';
        }
?>
```

BTW, I used ViewerJS, an open-source PDF viewer to display the files directly on the web-page, without downloading it. I might have to make some more changes in table, for giving user a link to download the file as well and enable admins to remove it, if they want to. But for the time being, its doing a fine job! :)